# reading, manipulating & displaying text file in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am pretty new to python. I am trying to read a text file using tkinter then do the manipulation and then finally display the results.So there are basically 3 steps.

Here is my sample file which will be fixed in format :

```
DOWN 07.11.2016 08:21:33 - 07.11.2016 08:22:33
UP   07.11.2016 09:41:07 - 09.11.2016 09:20:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:26:33 - 09.11.2016 08:35:33
UP   09.11.2016 08:23:33 - 09.11.2016 08:25:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:36:33 - 09.11.2016 08:38:33
DOWN 10.11.2016 08:36:33 - 10.11.2016 08:38:33
```

File contains information about UP & DOWN status.

STEP 1 :
open & Read file

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
interface = Tk()
def openfile():
    return filedialog.askopenfilename()
button = ttk.Button(interface, text="Open", command=openfile)  # <------
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

interface.mainloop()
```

STEP 2: Manipulation

Here I am trying to go through each line and checking if its DOWN then how much is the total downtime and from which date in this case(sample file) total downtime is 12 min.

STEP 3:
I want to display this 12 min as downtime after manipulation on the GUI screen.
so at last my output on tinkter screen should be

```
Total Downtime is 12 min from 07.11.2016 08:21:33
```

how can I achieve step 2 & 3, i went through lot of articles over internet but could not find anything really helpful to solve this.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import tkFileDialog as fileDialog
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tk
    fileDialog = Tk.filedialog

import datetime

 # Manipulation
def processText(lines):
    total = 0
    start = None
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        direction, date1, time1, _, date2, time2 = line.split()
        if direction != "DOWN": continue
        if start==None: start = date1 + ' ' + time1
        # 1
        D1, M1, Y1 = date1.split('.')
        h1, m1, s1 = time1.split(':')
        # 2
        D2, M2, Y2 = date2.split('.')
        h2, m2, s2 = time2.split(':')
        # Timestamps
        t1 = datetime.datetime(*map(int, [Y1, M1, D1, h1, m1, s1])).timestamp()
        t2 = datetime.datetime(*map(int, [Y2, M2, D2, h2, m2, s2])).timestamp()
        total += (t2-t1)
    return total, start

# Opening and updating
def openFile():
    filename = fileDialog.askopenfilename()

    fileHandle = open(filename, 'r')
    down, start = processText(fileHandle.readlines())
    txt = "Total Downtime is {0} min from {1}".format(down//60, start)
    textVar.set(txt)

    fileHandle.close()

 # Main
root = Tk.Tk()

button = Tk.Button(root, text="Open", command=openFile)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

textVar = Tk.StringVar(root)
label = Tk.Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
label.grid(column=1, row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response , I get below error when I run the same.
attached the traceback.
could you please advise.

Comment: Aldo just wanted to know Is there any alternative to this step
"filename = Tk.filedialog.askopenfilename() # Only works in 3.x" if I run in python 2.7.x ?

Comment: previous error is fixed once i imported "from tkinter import filedialog as fd"
but there is a new problem now. I have added the new traceback with error.

I have tried declaring "start" variable as global but this too doesn't help to solve it.

Comment: thanks for the fix , but the output shown is just below the Open button.
Is it possible to display the o/p in a box or prettified way ? AlsoIf i want to provide custom date from where I want the total downtime can It be done ? if this happens it would really solve the issue!! Thanks a lot in advance